# Pass by Reference VS Static Variable

Tags: c#

From my understanding passing a variable by reference means that the original variable that was passed into a function's parameters is changed. But also from my understanding a static variable means that the variable is changed when used as a parameter of a function. So don't both of these do the same thing?

Comment: *"a static variable means that the variable is changed when used as a parameter of a function."* - Could you show some code that demonstrates what you mean? This sounds really odd to me

Comment: @zackraiyan: I don't understand what your comment means.

Comment: A static variable means that there is only one instance of it; compared to a member variable, for which there will be one variable for each instance of that class. It's nothing to do with passing by reference.

Comment: `a static variable means that the variable is changed when used as a parameter of a function`- mind to explain it dude ?

Comment: If the static variable is set in the method, that change will be visible elsewhere - but that's not the same as passing the value of a static variable into a method as an argument for a value parameter. In that case, a change to the parameter value will *not* affect the static variable.

Comment: @zackraiyan: Rather than "you invented it" it would be much more constructive (and less frankly rude) to ask for an example, as UnholySheep did.

Comment: @DaisyShipton , sorry, i din't mean to be rude .. i rather thought it was a bit sarcastic :( sorry again :)

Answer (score 4):

> From my understanding passing a variable by reference means that the original variable that was passed into a function's parameters is changed.

That location is passed, so yes; since the caller supplied the location, the caller can see the change.

> But also from my understanding a static variable means that the variable is changed when used as a parameter of a function.

That's not what that means *at all*. A static field just exists as a field once per type (or per combination of generic type arguments). That's all it means. When you pass the *value* of a static field to a method, the value from the static field is read once and copied onto the stack, and that *copy* is passed to the method. The value of the static field will not be changed during the call.

---

Perhaps the confusion here is actually "reference types", not "pass by reference"; if a static field is actually a reference to an object, then *changes to the object* will be observed by all callers. But it isn't the field that changed: it is the object.